# error failure writing sector to hd0, 966 bad sectors - do i need to replace hard drive?

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, smart, badblocks

I recently wiped my laptop clean and installed Ubuntu 20.04.2. After installation, if I reboot the newly installed OS, I get the following error:

```
error: failure writing sector 0xbd80848 to `hd0'.

Press any key to continue...
```

When I press any key, I am unable to boot Ubuntu (the computer just freezes at startup). I rebooted on a Live OS (from a USB drive) and checked the state of my hard drives with the 'Disks' application. Here is the result:

[image]

This result of 966 bad sectors looks bad, but I don't know if this means I should replace my hard drive.

1. **What is the issue with my computer?**
2. **How do I fix bad sectors?**
3. **Do I need to replace my hard drive?**

---

### Update #1:

Responding to the comment by Hasan Merkit:

[image]

---

### Update #2:

Responding to answer given by @HappyTux, here is the output to the command  `systemctl status fstrim.timer` when using the Live OS.

```
systemctl status fstrim.timer
● fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: >
Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2021-03-19 20:02:39 UTC; 3 weeks 6 days>
Trigger: Mon 2021-03-22 00:00:00 UTC; 4 weeks 1 days left
Triggers: ● fstrim.service
Docs: man:fstrim
```

Comment: Can you check your hdd health with this tool? https://www.hdsentinel.com/hdslin/hdsentinel-018c.gz

More info: https://www.hdsentinel.com/hard_disk_sentinel_linux.php

Comment: @HasanMerkit See my update. Is this what you were looking for? Should I provide a more detailed diagnostic?

Answer (score 2):

Your drive is most likely dead, when the errors start to happen it is time get new one. You could try the bad blocks idea to mask them away but I have found they will soon die, like the 4TB I got rid of just this week, after doing that when the errors returned again.

And looking at that report in the updated posting as I posted that. It does nothing to dissuade me from that advice, if anything it confirms dying drive.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, how can I prevent this from happening in the future? This has never happened to me with any other disks. I thought I was taking care of this laptop quite well.

Comment: It does seem very young for a drive to die, I still have my original drive I bought a good ten years ago working. Only one SSD has died on me, make certain when you get new one in the machine that the trim command is enabled to ensure proper wear leveling, it seems to do it by default on my desktop, on my Pi I had to enable it manually. Hopefully it does it on your laptop too `fstrim -v /` will tell you if enabled right now when booted into the system to do a manual trimming or `systemctl status fstrim.timer` for the actual status of it.

Comment: See my update. I ran the second command you suggested.

Comment: That is too strange a weekly service is next scheduled to run a month later according to that output. Unfortunately it looks like it is time to move on with this drive. The checks alone with it showing only 11% health says it dies in days.

Comment: Yeah okay, good thing I'm able to access all my data using the live OS booting from a USB.